# Memory for crash kernel (0x0 to 0x0) not within permissable range

Tags: centos, centos5

When booting Centos 5.5 on a  vmbox  running on windows XP I get the following message.

Memory for  crash kernel (0x0 to 0x0) not within permissable range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading http://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS5.1

> During the boot process you may see the message "Memory for crash
>   kernel (0x0 to 0x0) notwithin
>   permissible range" appear. This
>   message comes from the new kdump
>   infrastructure. It is a harmless
>   message and can be safely ignored.

This is for CentOS 5.1, you can assume it's valid for 5.5 too

Answer (score 0):

Does the system boot into a useful state? or does the system hang there?

If it boots into a useful state, you can either ignore the message (like I do), or you can allocate some RAM for kdump via system-config-kdump.

If the system doesn't boot, it's rather more interesting.

Comment: The system boots ok.